# Javascript - event listener toggle button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a button which can toggle "double click" to "single click" and vice versa. For some reason, once it toggles to single click, it cannot toggle back. Can anyone please help?

```
function init() {
    normal_listeners();
}

function addListener(){
    var image1 = document.getElementById('image_1');
    var image2 = document.getElementById('image_2');
    var image3 = document.getElementById('image_3');

    if(document.getElementById('listener_1').value == "Listener"){
        document.getElementById('listener_1').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        alert("Normal");

        image1.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){userChoice(1);}, false);
        image2.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){userChoice(2);}, false);
        image3.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){userChoice(3);}, false); 

        document.getElementById('listener_1').value = "Normal";
    } 
    else if(document.getElementById('listener_1').value == "Normal") {
        document.getElementById('listener_1').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        alert("Listener");

        image1.addEventListener("click", function(){userChoice(1);}, false);
        image2.addEventListener("click", function(){userChoice(2);}, false);
        image3.addEventListener("click", function(){userChoice(3);}, false);

       document.getElementById('listener_1').value = "Listener";
   }
}

function normal_listeners(){
    var image1 = document.getElementById('image_1');
    var image2 = document.getElementById('image_2');
    var image3 = document.getElementById('image_3');
    var listener1 = document.getElementById('listener_1');

    listener1.addEventListener("click", addListener, false);    
    image1.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){userChoice(1);}, false);
    image2.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){userChoice(2);}, false);
    image3.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){userChoice(3);}, false);
 }
 window.onload = init;

 <img id="image_1" src="rock.jpg" alt="ROCK" width="100" height="100">
 <img id="image_2" src="paper.jpg" alt="PAPER" width="100" height="100">
 <img id="image_3" src="scissors.jpg" alt="SCISSORS" width="100" height="100">
 <input type="button" id="listener_1" value="Normal" style="background-color:red">
```

Comment: It looks like on button toggle you always bind event, but don't undbind previous.

Comment: Be careful with this code, if you have more than one listener on the same event on the same object, effects could be ... curious !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the event listeners before adding the new ones. The click-listener assigned might prevent the doubleclick-listener to occur.